# breaking a for loop with length decrement

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I found this code to convert an excel column name into a column number but having a hard time understanding the break condition for the loop

```
//function convert excel sheet column to number

toColumnNumber = (colName) => {
  let result = 0;
  for (let i = colName.length, j = 0; i--; j++) {
    result += Math.pow(26, i) * (colName.charCodeAt(j) - 64);
  }
  return result;
};
console.log(toColumnNumber("AB"));
```

it uses `i--` as a break condition and i can't understand how it can be used to break the loop. or is it just that is how javascript works when we use i-- as a break condition and it reaches 0 it breaks the loop?

Comment: `0` is considered false so the loop breaks when `i` becomes 0. `i > 0` would be more readable

Comment: in Javascript, `0`, `"" (empty string)`, `undefined`, `null` and `NaN` are falsy value. they all equal to false.

Comment: for ([declarations]; [conditional test]; [interations]) your loop starts with i set to length, j set to zero, The loop runs then tests the condition if true it runs the interaction and loops again. so yes it is counting down to zero.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As we keep decrementing the value of `i`, eventually it reaches `0` and that would be `falsy` and would stop the loop.

This is just a fancy way of doing:

```
for (let i = colName.length, j = 0; i > 0; j++, i--) {
    result += Math.pow(26, i) * (colName.charCodeAt(j) - 64);
  }
```

Comment: aah, so it leads to truthy and falsy value that would keep loop going and breaking, will keep that in mind, thanks